# MSAA Fails to find winforms controls

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, inspect, ui-testing

I am using Coded UI to automate an application. In the automation process a complex process happens inside the application (loading a PowerPoint inside the application). After this process I can't continue the test because MSAA unable to find any controls in the application.I am using Inspect.exe, before and after the automation fails. I have attached the screen shot of Inspect tool before and after the failure. Is there any solution to overcome this issue? I can't continue automation testing without restarting the application whenever I face this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated ! 
[image: Before Coded UI Fails (Inspect.exe)]

[image: After Coded UI Fails (Inspect.exe)]

Comment: You say "a complex process happens inside the application (loading a PowerPoint inside the application)" suggesting that your application uses custom controls. Coded UI cannot handle custom controls unless they have been written to support the MSAA or UIA interfaces. In the absence of such support the best Coded UI can do is via co-ordinates within the control. Adding support into custom controls is complex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, You are right after that complex process, if I try to record any actions all the controls are automatically declared as custom controls. Do you think is it possible to continue automation with coded UI for this situation?. I can't understand the meaning of "via co-ordinates within the control"

Comment: Coded UI generates code such as `Mouse.Click(SomeUiControl, new Point(10, 10));` where the `10,10` is the co-ordinate within the control. For simple controls the code could be replaced with `Mouse.Click(SomeUiControl)` but the generated code includes the co-ordinates to better support some more complex controls.

Comment: The Coded UI test should be able to continue but it really depends on how the custom control handles mouse movements and clicks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried with Mouse.Click(SomeUiControl) and uiWindow.DrawHighlight() no luck, exception is UITestControlNotFoundException and message is "Unable to find the top level element of the control", What can I do?. But when the controls are identified as custom controls, Inpect.exe with UIA can find the controls.Is there any way to change controls in UIA instead of MSAA or hand code UI controls in UIA?

Comment: `DrawHighlight` should be successful on the parent control of the custom control. I am not sure whether it will work on the custom control itself. Programs like `Inspect.exe` use difference mechanisms to Coded UI. Many people (including me) wonder why they work but Coded UI cannot use the same mechanisms. As per my first comment, you can add support for MSAA or UIA into a custom control but doing so is complex.

Comment: ok,Thanks. If there any way to hand-code failing controls in UIA Technology because after the failure White automation framework managed to identify the controls and supports to continue the testing.Since White using UIA is there any way to switch to UIA from MSAA within Coded UI? Because I prefer Coded UI than White. framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the screen resolution and screen size in windows settings.

Had the same issue in CodedUI.
Inspect tool didnt find controls in msaa mode
After changing the screen resolution and size,
It was able to find the controls.

Answer (score -1):

Coded UI supports WinForms and WinControls. I'll suggest you to find the WinWindow by using the code below:

```
`WinWindow samplewindow = new WinWindow();
 samplewindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "XXYYZZZ";
 samplewindow.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "XXYYYZZZ";
 WinButton uIButton = new WinButton(samplewindow);
 uIButton.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "XXYYYZZZ";
 Mouse.Click(uIButton, MouseButtons.Left, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.None, uIButton.GetClickablePoint());'
```