# Visual Studio 2013 CodedUI test

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I've just started developing UI tests for a WPF application with the Visual Studio 2013 CodedUI Test tool.  Others have reported a similar issue (not the same scenario), but no one has been able to figure out how to resolve the error during playback that states:

"Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action" 
It seems like the test tool can't find the correct control.  In my application, I'm loading user controls dynamically at runtime.  The user can load the same control a number of times; since the control represents a different document type.  Can I uniquely mark my controls so the tool can find the controls?  I tried setting the UIAutomationId with no luck.  I've tried using the crosshair tool...I've come to the conclusion, unless someone can tell me differently, this tool CAN NOT support a dynamically generated WFP application.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you just clicking on the uielement? Have you tried clicking x/y coordinate points of the dynamically created element instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using the recorder.  When you say try clicking the x/y coordinate points, is there a way to change the recorder to use x/y points vs. ui elements?  p.s.  Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

First use Inspect tool (Inspect.exe which comes with windows development kit) whether you can identify the dynamic controls using MSAA technology. Because MSAA can't identify the controls in some situation. Refer to this post [MSAA Fails to find winforms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499252/msaa-fails-to-find-winforms-controls)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when starting to develop a CodedUI test for our WPF application, the problem seems to be in the custom tabpage the control I needed was in.

I circumvented the problem by clicking on the x/y point of the control before doing anything with it (for example input text). This makes sure the control is focused.

Method I created:

```
 public void ClickControl(UITestControl uiTestControl)
    {
        var boundingRectangle = uiTestControl.BoundingRectangle;

        var xavg = boundingRectangle.Right - (boundingRectangle.Width / 2);
        var yavg = boundingRectangle.Bottom - (boundingRectangle.Height / 2);
        var point = new Point(xavg, yavg);
        Mouse.Click(point);
    }
```

Hope it works for you as well!

Comment: Thanks!  I solved my original problem by creating a unique name based on the instance count.

Comment: Now I'm having problems getting to a CheckBox control in a ListBox DataTemplate

Comment: What kind of problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I'm using a ListBox, with ListBox.ItemTemplate, with a DataTemplate of CheckBoxes.  The recorder can not find the Checkbox wrapped in the DataTemplate.  I've read controls within the DataTemplate don't expose the necessary properties, by default, to allow the Code UI recorder to find and access them.  This is my last hurdle.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you're not bound to using the recorder there is a clean way to find your controls in the Coded UI script by extending the UITestControl class.

Comment: Edit:

If you're not bound to using the recorder there is a clean way to find your controls in the Coded UI script by extending the UITestControl class. [More info here](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/03/build-a-coded-ui-test-without-a-ui-map/).


Otherwise you can try to use the arrows (not sure how to name it) in the tree view in the recorder to try and find the child controls once you've selected the DataTemplate. Shortcut is CTRL+I > Alt + Down.

Comment: Thanks, our testers are doing all the recording so we are trying to stick with the recorder.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you have multiple dynamically generated UI controls with the same Automation properties one solution is to use the Instance UITestControl search property to specify which instance of the control you'd like to access:

```
yourDuplicateControl.SearchProperties["Instance"] = "1";
```

Another solution which requires development side changes to your application is to have an `AutomationId` generated for the control which is unique to the Instance, for example setting `AutomationId` dynamically to the following:

```
yourDuplicateControlAutomationId1
yourDuplicateControlAutomationId2
yourDuplicateControlAutomationId3
```